# Locating MySite profile import data

Tags: 2007, my-site

I am attempting to find where our SharePoint 2007 MySite gets it's information from.

There are certain fields that are not updating correctly all the time. I have been unable to find where to even edit what fields are imported so far and have been digging into this issue for multiple days now.

My question is.

Where are the import settings for fields set and how can I find the database table it gains this information from?

If this is not possible without knowledge of what I am looking for please tell me and I will look for another route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Central Administration and then Shared Services.  Then click on user profile and properties and then view profile properties.

Here you will find the list of all user profile properties.  There is a column called Mapped Attribute which will display where that data is coming from.  By clicking on the property name and selecting edit from the menu, you can see further detail and change the import location under Property Import Mapping.